# how to include tests in a distributable django app?

Tags: python, django

I distribute a small django app that I wanted to write a test for. It uses some settings and I was importing

`from django.conf import settings`

in the app file but this leaves me with a problem because the standalone app has no django project so how would one write and run tests on it?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more details?

Comment: What more do you want to know? I am asking if I need to include a default django project WITH my redistributable app that people will install with `pip install myapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app folder, create a folder named `tests`, and in that folder place your tests (in a single `.py` file or multiple files.

You will end up with a folder structure like this:

```
my_app/
    tests/
        test_views.py
        test_other_stuff.py
```

Then you will be able to run your test suite for that app using:

```
`./manage.py test my_app`
```

Where `my_app` is the name of your app. As far as how to write the tests themselves, [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/) are very helpful.

Comment: you missed the point. I do not have a django project as this is the standalone app that I distribute. Do I really need to include a whole django project shell in my app when all I need is just one setting from it?

Comment: I am not sure if we have the same understanding of "project" and "app". What is it that you are distributing? A single file? An app folder? Either way, you can still include a test file or test folder. Look at similar apps and I am sure you will see the same thing. For example, one app that I use is `django-allauth`: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth. Note the `tests.py`.

Comment: I am distributing an app folder. 1. Do I need to include an entire django project to go with this app folder. 2. If not, how do I access a setting or at least mock it in some way so that I do not need an entire django project in my app?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a django project with the name of the app and then put all the distribution files such as

```
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
```

in the project level directory and then indicate only the files I want to include with the distribution in the MANIFEST.in file.

MAINFEST.in:

```
include myapp/*
```